# PvDeviceGEV.h(5) Error: Syntax error in input(1) --- C++ to Go using SWIG

Tags: c++, go, swig

I get the error described in the question topic. Here are the files below.

PvDeviceGEV.h

```
  #ifndef __PV_DEVICE_GEV_H__
  #define __PV_DEVICE_GEV_H__
  #include "PvDevice.h"

  class PV_DEVICE_API PvDeviceGEV : public PvDevice  <- error message points here
  {
     public:
        PvDeviceGEV();
        virtual ~PvDeviceGEV();
        PvResult SetStreamDestination( const PvString &aIPAddress, uint16_t aDataPort, uint32_t aChannel = 0 ); 
  };
 #endif // __PV_DEVICE_GEV_H__
```

I have Camera.swigcxx as follows

```
%module connectionRecovery_module
%{
#include "ConnectionRecovery.h"
#include "PvDevice.h"
#include "PvDeviceGEV.h"
%}
%include "ConnectionRecovery.h"
%include "PvDevice.h"
%include "PvDeviceGEV.h"
```

I dont have the .cpp files as they are locked in a DLL. Let me know if you need more information as to how to fix this error. I think I have to adjust the .swigcxx file but I am not sure. Thank you!

Comment: my first guess would be `PV_DEVICE_API`. What is it?

Comment: @user463035818  I think you are correct. PV_DEVICE_API is #define PV_DEVICE_API __declspec( dllimport )

Comment: `#define __PV_DEVICE_GEV_H__` That idenfitifer is reserved. By using it, your programs behaviour will be undefined. You should use another header guard.

Comment: @eerorika Are you suggesting to replace #define _PV_DEVICE_GEV_H with, for example, #define PVDEVICEGEV_H ?

Comment: @DanielRamsey The latter is not reserved. Should be fine as long as that macro isn't used by any other file that you include. `_PV_DEVICE_GEV_H` is reserved just like the original was.

Comment: @eerorika gotcha, unfortunately I still get the same error after the changes but ill look into this more